# Automatically Checking A Checkbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a main form in MS Access 2013 that we will call "Leads" with several sub forms on it such as addresses, phone number, ect. I have a checkbox for each sub form to indicate when a record is entered. Once the user enters a record they should check the checkbox so I know that I need to followup with that record. Is there a way to automatically check the checkbox once a record has been entered without the user having to do it. i have tried to get it to work with a data macro as described in the post from another using a donstion sheet. i am sure there is a vba solution to this but i dont have a clue to how to do it

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Yes, there is a way but let us know what did you try... or research...

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties sheet, set the property *DefaultValue* of the checkbox to: *True*

Comment: _Is there a way to automatically check the checkbox once a record has been entered [created] without the user having to do it_ . Don't mind the cowardly downvote. This is how to achieve this - with zero code.

Comment: Indeed the easiest way.